# How can I use ElephantSQL (Postgresql) with a Clojure app?

Tags: postgresql, clojure, cloudbees

I added the [ElephantSQL](http://www.elephantsql.com/) add-on to my cloudbees(?) hosted service and named the DB.

I've seen documentation on the MySQL service, and how to integrate it, but nothing for ElephantSQL.

Do I need environment config settings, or a connection string, or what?

On Heroku, I use DATABASE_URL config variable as my connection string.

Comment: Added it *to what*? See edit above - is that right? Please be more specific. We don't know what you're doing or where, you need to explain.

Comment: I have a working Clojure ring app that runs locally with Postgresql and also on Heroku, with the Postgresql backend.  I'd like to try cloudbees.  I have a free account, and I can either try deploying by git or a direct upload.  I assume the direct upload is a jar or war file, I'm not sure.  Either way, I need to know what I need to do in the project to connect to the ElephantSQL add-on that I have provisioned for this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We recommend using BoneCP and `clojure.java.jdbc`:

```
(ns myapp.db
  (:import com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource)
  (:import java.net.URI)
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
            [clojure.string :as string]))

(def url (get (System/getenv) "ELEPHANTSQL_URL" "postgres://localhost/mydb"))

(defn pool [url]
  (let [uri (URI. url)
        host (.getHost uri)
        port (if (pos? (.getPort uri)) (.getPort uri) 5432)
        path (.getPath uri)
        user-info (or (.getUserInfo uri) ":")
        [user password] (string/split user-info #":")]
    {:datasource
     (doto (BoneCPDataSource.)
       (.setJdbcUrl (str "jdbc:postgresql://" host ":" port path))
       (.setPartitionCount 1)
       (.setMinConnectionsPerPartition 3)
       (.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition 10)
       (.setUsername user)
       (.setPassword password))}))

(def pooled-db (delay (pool url)))

(defn account [id]
  (jdbc/query
    @pooled-db
    ["SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = ?" id]))
```